# Como aumentar performance no PHP?

Tags: php, desempenho, gerenciamento-de-memória, memory-limit

Se eu aumentar a `memory_limit` (padrão: 256MB) nas configurações do PHP, a minha aplicação irá executar mais rápido ou vou acabar perdendo performance por ela consumir mais processamento da CPU do servidor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aumentar o limite da memória em si não aumenta carga do processador. É possível que algum algoritmo funcione melhor por ter mais memória disponível, mas é algo pontual e precisaria ser mensurado.

Aumentar o limite de memória aumenta a chance de não caber tudo na memória RAM e fazendo *swap* pra disco pode tornar a performance trágica.

Para obter mais performance não pode ser um processo aleatório, tem que definir requisitos, onde está o gargalo e procurar estratégias que atendam aquilo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).